# main.cpp ignores *.c (not cpp) - undefined reference

Tags: c++, c, gcc

I've faced some strange error with gcc and undefined reference error.
I've create simple test project which I compile with gcc:

**main.cpp**

```
#include "func.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    func();
}
```

**func.h**

```
void func();
```

**func.c**

```
void func()
{
}
```

The project itself build using `QtCreator` so all `Makefiles` etc were build automatically. The build commands are:

> g++ -o debug\main.o main.cpp
>
> gcc -o debug\func.o func.c
>
> g++ -o debug\app.exe debug/main.o debug/func.o

after that I get error:

> main.cpp:9: undefined reference to `func()'

Ok, after lots of attempts I noticed that `*.c` file has compiled with `gcc` and `*.cpp` with `g++`. But does it mean? Is `*.obj` files formats are different? The problem was solved by changing extension from `*.c` to `*.cpp` but this still interesting what happened here.

Comment: You need `extern "C" { ... }` in the header.

Comment: Look up "name mangling".